# What is difference between Angular2 @Injectable and and non injectable service

Tags: angular

In `angular` `@injectable` annotated class and normal plain typescript, classes are injected as angular service. They both injected and used in same was at the module level and also in the component level

> What is the difference?

At what situation we should use @Injectable class and at what situation we should use a normal class?

```
providers: [MyResourcesList]
```

Injectable service declaration

```
@Injectable()
export class WidgetResourcesList { }
```

normal typescript service declaration

```
export class WidgetResourcesList { }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With @Injectable() annotation you mark your service as injectable for other components / services / pipes.

providers: [] is a dependency container. You register your injectable service in the container.

Comment: how to inject an Injectable service in component. When create on variable of type of that injectable class, I am getting error in my browser (its not a typescript error) while running the application?

Comment: could you give a sample? Use constructor injection. export class MyComponent { constructor (private widget: WidgetResourcesList) {} method(){this.widget.foo()}}